# Jquery append or add

Tags: jquery, html-agility-pack

im creating a mobile website from an existing (older) website.
The content from the original website gets loaded in the mobile page troughout HTML agility pack.

The original site has a page similar to this:

```
<p>
<a href="#">Link1</a>
<a href="#">Link2</a>
<a href="#">Link3</a>
<a href="#">Link4</a>
</p>
```

What i want to do is to insert "content1" underneat "link1", "content2" underneat "link2" and so on. I want to do this by using jQuery. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`jQuery` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) (usually aliased as `$`) to select the anchor you want to add after, and then use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to insert content after it. You'll need a CSS selector for the anchor. We can't give you one that's guaranteed to work from the small markup given, but it'll be something like:

```
$("blah blah p a:eq(0)").after("content after link1");
$("blah blah p a:eq(1)").after("content after link2");
```

...where "blah blah" gives us a bit more context, so we're not adding that text after the first anchor in *every* paragraph, which I'm guessing you wouldn't want. :-)

If there's no context you can use other than the content of the links, you *could* use the [`:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector):

```
$("a:contains('Link1')").after("content after link1");
```

...but beware that it will match any anchor that contains the text "link1" *anywhere* within it, and the selector may not be provided by the underlying browser which means jQuery would have to do the search internally, which is a bit slower.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried with [1] but that failed thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a $.each() if you want to change all of them

```
$.each($('p a'), function(i,e){$(e).after('content'+i+')});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
var content = {'0' : 'Content 1','1' : 'Content 2','2' : 'Content 3','3' : 'Content 4' };

jQuery("#anyparentId p a").each(function(index){
    jQuery(this).after('<p>'+content[index]+'</p>');
});
```